# Tag value not printing etree lxml

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I want to print the "Printable String" part of the code. Also I tried to print the whole tag itself but didn't find a way to print the whole tag instead of just the tag name. Retrieving Xpath and the whole tag itself is the biggest challenge currently, Thank You!

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

doc = "<p><a></a><a></a>Printable String</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "lxml")
root = etree.fromstring(str(soup))

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
for i, e in enumerate(root.iter()):
    print(e.text)
```

Output:

```
None
None
None
None
None
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Expected Output:

```
None 
None
Printable String
None 
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to notice:

First, for some reason you parse `doc` first with `soup` and then again parse the string of `soup` with lxml. The first problem is that BS doesn't leave the string along. If you

```
print(soup)
```

the output is

```
<html><body><p><a></a><a></a>Printable String</p></body></html>
```

You will notice two new elements (`html` and `body`) are now added, which explains why you get five `None`s instead of only three.

If you parse `doc` directly with lxml like so and use xpath:

```
doc = "<p><a></a><a></a>Printable String</p>"
root = etree.fromstring(doc)
for z in root.xpath('//*'):
    print(z.xpath('text()'))
```

Output is

```
['Printable String']
[]
[]
```

Comment: Can you tell me what are the other functions similar to text(), and is there a way to get the actual tag as a whole and use it for comparison purposes

Comment: @AnduGunduSwami Glad it worked for you! As to you other comment - not sure what you mean by "get the actual tag as a whole". I would suggest you post it as a new question, and in there show your exact expected output. I (and others) would be better able to answer that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = "<p><a></a><a></a>Printable String</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "lxml")
print(soup.find('p').text)
```

...or if you want a pure etree solution then:-

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

doc = '<p><a></a><a></a>Printable String</p>'

tree = etree.parse(StringIO(doc))
print(tree.xpath('//p/text()')[0])
```

Comment: Its an alternate, I want to get solution using lxml etree

Comment: Why did you import BeautifulSoup if you want a pure etree solution?

Comment: if there are any unclosed tags in you html code, just like browsers BeautifulSoup closes it automatically and lxml doesn't do it, that's why I converted it to BeautifulSoup obj first

Comment: Fair enough but there's nothing in your original question to suggest that you're working with HTML

Comment: I added a small sample but forgot to make it more descriptive, my bad